# SQL: Link table1 and table2 with a merged row then link to table3

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm breaking my head over this problem but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Table setup

[image]

1) Join table1 & table2

2) Join this with table3

First part of the question I sloved.
The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN 
     Table2 
     ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
```

But when I want to include table3 in the query I get an error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN 
      Table2 
      ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
     ) INNER JOIN 
     Table3 
     ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

Error:

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: What database? Access? I think you don't need the parentheses otherwise.

Comment: Most DBMSes require that a `derived table` be given an `alias`.

Answer (score 1):

Using nested select requiers giving it alias

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
Table1.Name
, Table1.LastName
, Table2.FullName
, Table2.id AS table2_id
  Table1 LEFT JOIN 
      Table2 
      ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
) AS T
INNER JOIN 
     Table3 
     ON T.table2_id= Table3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't need to use a subquery. Most likely, the following query should be sufficient in your use case :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
    INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's a syntax error. Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
      ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
INNER JOIN Table3 
     ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

In addition: as you are referencing the outered join table in the second join, use a left join there too. So like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
      ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
LEFT JOIN Table3 
     ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Table1
LEFT JOIN  Table2
       ON  Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
INNER JOIN Table3
        ON Table2.id = Table3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access has arcane rules about outer joins.  I think you want two outer joins anyway.  Does this work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN 
      Table2 
      ON Table1.Name & " " & Table1.LastName = Table2.FullName
     ) LEFT JOIN 
     Table3 
     ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

Comment: Yes I think my problem was something with these inner joins. 
Although now I get empty values, but I can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from Table1 t1,Table2 t2,Table3 t3
where 
t1.Name||' '||t1.LastName=t2.FullName and
t2.Id=t3.Id
```